# Why can I not download rails?

Tags: ruby-1.9.3

I use Windows XP Pro. I'm new to ruby.

At 12:35 GMT, I issued the following command plus response:

> C:>gem install rails
>
> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
>             Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ETIMEDOUT: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did
>    not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Maybe I should just try later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my VPN.I work from home.

I disconnected the VPN, and now everything works OK.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe I should just try later?

Yup, most likely. This doesn't look like an error that is caused by your side.